# ConnectionError when send request to https page with python

Tags: python-3.x, http, https

I am trying to implement program that determine, if page support tls or not and if it is needed to have prefix `www`. So I am testing page1.cz and check response status of this objects:

```
Session().get('http://page1.cz')
<Response [200]>
Session().get('http://www.page1.cz')
<Response [200]>
Session().get('https://page1.cz')
<Response [200]>
Session().get('https://www.page1.cz')
<Response [200]>
```

It works fine, I know that page1.cz is using https and it is always redirect to `https://page1.cz`. When I tried page2.cz, I recieved error when testing with `https` prefix. I receiving this error:

```
Session().get('http://page2.cz')
<Response [200]>
Session().get('http://www.page2.cz')
<Response [200]>
Session().get('https://page2.cz')
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='page2.cz', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f75e85f03c8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
Session().get('https://www.page2.cz')
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.page2.cz', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f75e85f03c8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

I know that second page does not support `https` but why that error? It should just return code 4xx or am I wrong? What am I doing wrong and how to check if page support `http`, `https` and `www` prefixes?

Comment: You made too many requests and got banned from accessing the website. It is a policy matter and has nothing to do with HTTPS or w/e.

Comment: @DYZ It's not a matter of being banned, it's the exception raised when a connection is refused

Comment: But it is refused because the OP got banned.

Comment: I tried it once and recieved this error. Now, after one hour I am receiving the same error. @newbie am I understand right that the connection refused is because it does not support https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that the host refused the connection and an error is raised.

You can handle the exception using a `try-except` block.

```
import requests

try:
    req = requests.get(your_website)
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
    print("Connection refused")
```

Additionally you can set a timeout for the request, e.g.,

```
req = requests.get(your_website, timeout=1)
```

Consider for instance the following website http://www.qq.com/ that does not support https.

With `your_website` being `http://www.qq.com/` you would receive a 200 OK, while with `your_website` being `https://www.qq.com/` an exception is raised.

Comment: So that means, everything works as it should? I except that it will return error code other than 2xx  (e.g. 404). I know I could hande excepion, but it looks very unpractical solution. Is there a better way how to check if website support https?

Comment: So it is normal behaviour to raise an exception when https is not supported?

Comment: Note that you could also receive it as a response when HTTP is not supported and a redirect has not being implemented in the server.